# Sorting data based on cell value copied to new worksheets that can also work in reverse

Tags: excel, sorting

Trying to work this the base way possible.  I'm trying to create an inventory list that can sort based on master storage locations.  the Master list or "MASTER LIST PAGE" will hold ALL the data that is entered.  It will then sort data based on a drop down box with selections i have added for storage locations.  These will then be sorted to the named sheets.  I'm also hoping to track changes to from each sheet to another.  Here is the basic set up

"MASTER SHEET" (main page holds all data)
Truck E-1 (any data on the master sheet in column "F" that contains "E-1" would be sorted to the "TRUCK E-1" sheet
Truck E-4 (same as above but looking for "E-4" in column "F"
This could go on for many different keywords and sorted areas

If the item is moved from "Truck E-1" sheet to "truck E-4" then it would be removed from the "Truck E-1" sheet and placed in "Truck E-4".  The Master list should also update to show the item in E-4 now.

The item should not be removed from the master list and there are several other other storage locations on the site.  The idea is to be able to transfer and track items on different pages and on the master list.

Not even sure if this is possible in excel, but figured i would ask.

Thanks

Comment: It seems like there are 4 requirements here:  1) Master that is the system of record and the controlling account.  2) SubLists that derive from Master that appear when button "X" is pressed along with selections from dropdown(s).  3) Change list that records Inserts/Updates/Deletes from the Master.  4) Propagation of Insert/Update/Delete into the SubLists.  These 4 are probably doable in Excel, but using a DataBase could eliminate SubLists and Propagation and make it simpler.  So, why are the SubLists a requirement?  separate sheets for each of the locations?

Comment: The sublist are like you said, separate sheet for each location.  The idea being that at anytime someone can look at any of the pages and print off just what is in the location for dispatch or accountability.  The master list would simply keep track of everything and any new information that is entered.  Not sure what you mean by using a database, would that still be excel or would that require a different program.  Pretty sure that every user would be stuck with excel.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) The database could be MS Access.  Along with a VBA program to allow one person at a time to Insert/Update/Delete rows in the Master table, and at the same time Insert a row into the Change table.  All at once, from one program. 2) A screen for Read-only users that would have selection dropdown(s) and a button "X" that would retrieve and show on the screen the selected rows, and allow for printing them.  The excel way allows for many hands in the master table with possibility of missing propagation and missing change table.